# Writing to a new Blob in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, blob, outputstream

I want to be able to create a new Blob object and then write to it. Originally, my general plan for this was as follows:

Create a new blob (null, because there's no Blob constructor)
Create a new OutputStream and set it to blob.setBinaryStream(0)
Write to the output stream.

However, I get a NullPointerException when I try to execute this code. Is there a different way I should be going about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

~B

Comment: Is this a `java.sql.Blob` that you want to write to a database?

Comment: "However, I get a NullPointerException when I try to execute this code" - DUH! I'd suggest re-reading your own question...you're trying to invoke a method on a `null` reference...sheesh!

Comment: @Marcelo, very likely yes. `setBinaryStream` is a method of `java.sql.Blob`.

Comment: I think Howard's answer will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Vineet `PreparedStatement` also has a `setBinaryStream` method.

Comment: @Jesper, yes, but the point was that OP does not appear to be doing anything involving a database in the first place; at least it wasn't apparent from the question.

Comment: @mre you don't have to be rude!

@everyone else: we are NOT trying to write this to a database, and we're not drawing it from a database either (obviously, otherwise I wouldn't be trying to deal with a null blob) -- so PreparedStatements aren't in the cards, @Vineet is correct. :)

Comment: @Benjadette, the java.sql.* classes are meant to be used in a context where SQL and JDBC are involved. You ought to be using an appropriate class from a different package. Perhaps ByteBuffers are what you need.

Answer (score 4):

`java.sql.Blob` is an interface and not a class, thus no constructor can exist. But you can instantiate the implementing class `SerialBlob` which allows you to construct a blob from a byte array.

Comment: But I don't want to fill it with anything, and SerialBlob takes either a blob or a byte array. Giving it a null blob obviously produces the same issue -- and I am not sure about giving it an empty byte array but it seems like that would pose the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Create a new blob (null, because there's no Blob constructor) Create a new OutputStream and set it to blob.setBinaryStream(0) Write to the output stream.
>
> However, I get a NullPointerException when I try to execute this code.

Yes, that's not a surprise - you will get a `NullPointerException` when you try to call a method on a variable that is `null` (as is your `blob` variable).

You should call `setBinaryStream` on your `PreparedStatement` object instead. Suppose that you have the data in a `byte[]`, then you could do something like this:

```
byte[] data = ...;

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(...);

ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

ps.setBinaryStream(1, stream);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I'm not using PreparedStatements (I'm not feeding it back to a database). Do you know of any way I can do this without a PreparedStatement? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean; why would you want to make a `Blob` if you're not going to put it in the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Blob in a CallableStatement or a PreparedStatement, you don't actually need to create a Blob object itself. The `setBlob` methods come in flavors that take an InputStream in place of a Blob object. You could, for instance, write to a ByteArrayOutputStream, retrieve the byte array, and then wrap that in a ByteArrayInputStream. Or you could use piped streams.

Comment: I'm not using Prepared or Callable statements because I'm not outputting to a database. Do you know of any other way I could accomplish this?

Comment: You can either use a SerialBlob as Howard suggested, or write your own Blob implementation. (It's all pretty straightforward except for the `position` methods.)

Comment: If you're not using a data base, why do you need a Blob object? Perhaps there's some other way of accomplishing what you need.

Comment: Yes, good point -- we had started with a plan to write to the database, which is why we had the blob implementation... But now that I look at the code, I am not so sure it is necessary. thanks!